# How to prove $\bar{x}$ is UMVUE estimator for lambda without using CRLB?

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, umvue

How to prove $\bar{x}$ is UMVUE for lambda for poission distribution without using CRLB(cramer-rao lower bound)?

Comment: Hint: Lehmann-Scheffe and the properties of exponential families.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Nicole, you've had numerous questions placed on hold for the same reason. Please don't post more questions until you have read the [on-topic help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the  `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). In particular, you need to show an attempt that we can help you take the next step with.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank for your recommendation. I won't post any questions for this week. I worked for a long time about those qustions I posted. Just posted those quesitons in a time. Sorry about this.

Comment: If you worked on them for a long time, you should be able to show us some of the working. Please edit your questions as suggested, so we can take them off hold.

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited the other two questions, showing what I can reach right now. I am still working on those two questions. As long as I worked them out, I will post an answer. For this one, since I haven't learned Lehmann-Scheffe, I use E(x1|x bar) as posted in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You could edit the Q to point out you haven't done Lehmann-Scheffe yet, and ask if your approach (the one in your current answer) is a good one.

Comment: @Glen_b I think we learned Lehmann-Scheffe, the professor didn't tell us this name. I change my answer posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By showing that $\bar{x}$ is a complete sufficient statistic for lambda, $\bar{x}$ is an UMVUE since it is a function of itself(a complete sufficient statistic for lambda). I didn't notice this point before.

Comment: Using Rao-Blackwell only creates unnecessary work.  Just appeal to Lehmann-Scheffe as @user777 already pointed out.

Comment: @dsaxton I didn't learn Lehmann-Scheffe. My understanding about this is $\bar{x}$ is a complete sufficient statisitc for lambda(property of exponential family) and thus $\bar{x}$ is UMVUE for lambda, right